# Python constraint adding variable with fixed value

Tags: python, constraints

I have this code:

```
variables = range(0, 16)
domain = range(1, 5)

problem.addVariable(variables[15],[4])
problem.addVariables(variables[:15], domain)
problem = Problem()
```

The 15th varible value is 4 but i want to make the fixed value of the 12th variable to be 1. How do add all variables expect the 12th and the 15th?

Something like this:

```
problem.addVariable(variables[15],[4])
problem.addVariable(variables[12], [1])
problem.addVariables(variables[0:12,13:15], domain)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
problem.addVariable(variables[15],[4])
problem.addVariable(variables[12], [1])
new_variables = variables[11:] + variables[13:14] + variables[:16]
problem.addVariables(new_variables,domain)
```

Comment: Tried this and i am getting: "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'range'"

Comment: so you have to convert the range to a list : variables = list ( variables ) ////// and /////// domain = list ( domain )